# System.Printing.Addjob() Error in Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

So I am trying to create a script that will take a print job from one paused print queue and add it to an active queue. However I am trying to utilize the AddJob() function and upon calling it with or without parameters it returns an exception and I am not sure why. Here is what I have so far

```
$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing
$permissions = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer
$queueperms = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministratePrinter
$server = new-object System.Printing.PrintServer -argumentList $permissions
$queues = $server.GetPrintQueues(@([System.Printing.EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes]::Shared))

foreach ($q in $queues) { 
    if ($q.IsPaused -eq 1)
    {
        $qPaused = new-object System.Printing.PrintQueue -argumentList $server,$q.Name,1,$queueperms
    }
    else 
    {
        $qPlaying = new-object System.Printing.PrintQueue -ArgumentList $server,$q.Name,2,$queueperms
    }
}

$byteContents = @('This is a test')
$byteContents | Out-File -FilePath "C:\testinput.txt"
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content -Encoding byte -Path "C:\testinput.txt"
#$printJob = $qPaused.GetJob(3).
$qPlaying.AddJob()
$jobStream = $printJob.JobStream
$jobStream | Out-GridView
#$jobStream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
#$jobStream.Close()
```

What this gives me is an error at the $qPlaying.AddJob() saying

```
Exception calling "AddJob" with "0" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: clientPrintSchemaVersion"
At line:23 char:1
+ $qPlaying.AddJob()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the Print Schema is defined when you call the constructor for the queue in this line:

```
$qPlaying = new-object System.Printing.PrintQueue -ArgumentList $server,$q.Name,2,$queueperms
```

You are using [PrintQueue Constructor (PrintServer, String, Int32, PrintSystemDesiredAccess)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552262(v=vs.110).aspx) where the `Int32` is the Print Queue Schema version. The MSDN article has a remark that: *"The Print Schema version released with Windows Vista is "1"."* Which would make sense that when you use `2` and receive an out of range error that `2` isn't an acceptable value.

You could use `1` as the value or use an [alternate constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552255(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
$qPlaying = new-object System.Printing.PrintQueue -ArgumentList $server,$q.Name,$queueperms
```